# Brave from ignorance and folly

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, phrases, prepositions

I read a sentence:

> It is not fortitude to be brave from ignorance and folly.

Why we use *from* in the construction *brave from*?

What is the full meaning of the sentence?

Comment: I'd say it's non-standard or at least unnatural sounding in this example, and would use 'as a result of' instead.

Comment: Or try “*out of*”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "...to be brave because you are ignorant and foolish".

A person who goes into a dangerous situation even though they are fully aware of the risks is more truly brave than one who rushes in without stopping to think.

Comment: Thanks please also tell- is it correct to use 'from' after brave. It would be great if you could give another example. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly correct to speak of doing something _from ignorance_ - in this case, _being brave_. "He acted from ignorance in not applying the correct first aid procedure."

Comment: Admittedly I only get a surprising 4000 hits on Google for "acted from ignorance",  but the 2 distinct hits for "brave from ignorance" would seem to support my feeling that this particular string is unidiomatic. 'From' meaning 'as a result of' [+ NP or ing-clause]  seems to be fairly selective wrt complement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **from** should be used here, rather **out of**.

Here is an example in an article heading:
[Objective knowledge out of ignorance: Popper on body, mind, and the third world](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00167591)

Another one:
[Probability magic or knowledge out of ignorance](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229887519_Probability_magic_or_knowledge_out_of_ignorance)

Answer (score 0):

*from* is a funny little word undervalued in English in favor of *of*.

By my estimate the *-m* marks the case, which had come to supplement the ablativ and vocative in Germanic tongues. Compare *whom, him*; German dative *von wem* instead of genitive *wessen*, ca. "of whom" and "whose"; Latin accusative *quam*, "in what way".

This is notable because *pro* or *fro* (as in "to and fro, back and forth") are usually directed at the target, cp. e.g. *in front of*. Also cp. Latin *per* "via", Fr. *par excelence*.

It still makes sense however to read *pro*, only in reversed direction. I acknowledge that that is not really a satisfying conclusion.

Nevertheless, it is not too far off the mark, if en.wiktionary is correctly giving a reconstructed sense "2. (*used with dative*) by, due to" for [*fram](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/fram).